# PHP - Cannot update the cart total amount in Session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

As the title says, I cannot update the cart total amount. Here's the scenario of my situation.

I have a checkout page in which there is an option of shipping amount in which the user has to select an option from the drop down menu. Once chosen, the cart total amount should get updated adding the shipping charges in the header where my navigation links are and also in the page where I want the user to click the button for checking out.

Here's the shipping charge HTML code:

```
<select name="selectZone" id="custDelAddZone">
    <option value="-1">----- Select -----</option>
    <?php
    $queryForZone = "SELECT * FROM shipping_zones ORDER BY ZoneName";
    $validate->Query($queryForZone);
    if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['ZoneId'].'">'.$row['ZoneName'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>                   
<button name="CustDelAddUpdateZone" id="btnCustDelAddUpdateZone" type="submit">Continue</button>
```

Here's the AJAX part of the button click:

```
$("#btnCustDelAddUpdateZone").click(function() {
    zoneId = $("#custDelAddZone").val();
    if (zoneId == '-1') {
        toastr.error("Please Select The Region", "Error");
        toastr.options.showMethod = "slideDown";
        toastr.options.hideMethod = "slideUp";
    }
    var dataStr = $("#chooseShippingZoneForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/ECommerceOnFlatastic/ActionFiles/Customers/UpdateDeliveryZone.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataStr,
        success: function(msg) {
            toastr.success(msg);
            toastr.options.showMethod = "slideDown";
            toastr.options.hideMethod = "slideUp";

            $("#selectZoneForm").slideUp();
            $("#delMethod h3").removeClass("color_light active");
            $("#paytMethod").show();
            $("#paytMethod h3").removeClass("bg_light_color_1 color_dark");
            $("#paytMethod h3").addClass("color_light active");
            $("#payment").slideDown();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

And here's the PHP script (UpdateDeliveryZone.php):

```
<?php
session_start();

$zoneId = $custCode = "";

require_once '../../Classes/class.Validation.php';
$validate = new Validation('developi_ecommerce');

$q = "SELECT CustCode FROM customers WHERE CustEmailAdd = '".$_SESSION['Customer']['email']."'";
$validate->Query($q);
if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
    while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
        $custCode = $row['CustCode'];
    }
} else {
    echo "No Customer Found";
}

if ( isset( $_POST['selectZone'] ) && $_POST['selectZone'] != "" ) {
    $zoneId = $validate->EscapeString( $_POST['selectZone'] );
    $query = "UPDATE customers_delivery_address SET ZoneId = '".$zoneId."' WHERE CustCode = '".$custCode."' AND CustDelAddLastInserted >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE";
    if ( $validate->Query( $query ) == TRUE ) {
        echo "Updated Successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Query";
    }
} else {
    echo "Value Not Set";
}
?>
```

And here's how I am trying to get the cart total amount in PHP:

```
if ($validate->Query($sql) == TRUE) {
    if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
        while ( $row = $validate->FetchAllDatas() ) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="width: 50%;" data-title="Product Image &amp; name" class="t_md_align_c"><img src="images/Products/'.$row['ProdCode'].'.jpg" alt="'.$row['ProdCode'].'" class="m_md_bottom_5 d_xs_block d_xs_centered" height="75" width="75"><a href="product.php?code='.$row['ProdCode'].'" class="d_inline_b m_left_5 color_dark">'.$row['ProdName'].'</a></td>';
            echo '<td style="width: 5%;" data-title="SKU">'.$row['ProdCode'].'</td>';
            echo '<td style="width: 5%;" data-title="Price"><p class="f_size_large color_dark">Rs. '.$row['ProdRate'].'</p></td>';
            echo '<td  style="width: 5%;" data-title="Quantity"><div class="clearfix d_inline_middle f_size_medium color_dark m_bottom_10">'.$_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'].'</div></td>';

            $sbTotal = $row['ProdRate'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'];
            $subTotal = $sbTotal;
            echo '<td style="width: 5%;" data-title="Subtotal"><p class="f_size_large fw_medium scheme_color t_align_r">'.number_format($sbTotal, 2).'</p></td>';
            $total += $subTotal;
            $_SESSION['cartTotalAmount'] = $total;
            $tax = $row['CatTaxPercent'];
            $taxAmt = (($sbTotal * $tax ) / 100);
            $taxAmount += $taxAmt;
            $amt = 0;
            $cartWeightPerProduct = ($row['weight'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity']);
            echo '</tr>';
            $totalCartWeight += $cartWeightPerProduct;
        }
        $totalTaxAmount += $taxAmount;

        $_SESSION['cartWeight'] = $totalCartWeight; 

        $sessAmnt = ($total + $totalTaxAmount);
        $totalPayableAmnt = $sessAmnt + $_SESSION['TotalWeight']; // This is my cart total amount

        $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] = number_format($totalPayableAmnt, 2);
        if ( isset( $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] ) ) {
            $amt = $totalPayableAmnt;
        } else {
            $amt = "Rs. 0";
        }

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Cart Total:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'.number_format($total, 2).'</p></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Taxes:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'. number_format($totalTaxAmount, 2) .'</p></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Shipping:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p id="shippingAmount" class="f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'.number_format($_SESSION['TotalWeight'], 2).'</p></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Total Payable Amount:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'.number_format($amt, 2).'</p></td></tr>';
    }
}
```

For those who wants to know from where the `$_SESSION['TotalWeight']` came from:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'Classes/class.Validation.php';

function SelectZoneAmount($amt, $id) {
    $validate = new Validation('developi_ecommerce');
    $zoneCol = 0;
    if ($amt >= 1 && $amt <= 499 ) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_0_500';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 500 && $amt <= 999) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_500_1000';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 1000 && $amt <= 1499) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_1000_1500';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 1500 && $amt <= 1999) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_1500_2000';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 2000 && $amt <= 2499) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_2000_2500';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 2500 && $amt <= 2999) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_2500_3000';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 3000 && $amt <= 3499) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_3000_3500';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 3500 && $amt <= 3999) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_3500_4000';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 4000 && $amt <= 4499) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_4000_4500';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 4500 && $amt <= 4999) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_4500_5000';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    } elseif($amt >= 5000 && $amt <= 10000) {
        $zoneCol = 'SWC_5000_10000';
        $query = "SELECT $zoneCol FROM shipping_weight_charges WHERE ZoneId = '".$id."'";
        $validate->Query($query);
        while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
            return $row[$zoneCol];
        }
    }
}
$region = 0;
if (isset($_POST['selectZone'])) {
    $region = SelectZoneAmount($_SESSION['cartWeight'], $_POST['selectZone']);
    $_SESSION['TotalWeight'] = $region;
    echo number_format($_SESSION['TotalWeight'], 2);
}

?>
```

When I go to checkout page and select the shipping zone, I am not able to refresh the cart total amount. I know there must be a logical error somewhere. Kindly help me in rectifying the error.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can anybody help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, error is found:

```
 $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] = number_format($totalPayableAmnt, 2);
```

you set value in `session var` by using `number_format()` function. this is wrong way.

you can use  `number_format()`  function only view section...

because,  `number_format()` return a string . so, it can't calculate.

Please check your code based on above condition.
then that may solve.

Comment: Nope. `$_SESSION['TotalWeight'];` is the amount from where I am getting the shipping amount from the database based on the products weight.

Comment: here, `$sbTotal = $row['ProdRate'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'];
            $subTotal = $sbTotal;
            echo '<td style="width: 5%;" data-title="Subtotal"><p class="f_size_large fw_medium scheme_color t_align_r">'.number_format($sbTotal, 2).'</p></td>';
            $total += $subTotal;
            `  $total may not defined..

Comment: In which part ? `$_SESSION['TotalWeight'];` is coming from the last part of the code.

Comment: Part four . you can `$total` is define before `while` loop as `$total=0;`  And code is large . so i can't detect error only read or see.

Comment: Nope.. still the same.. I have to refresh the whole page once again which I don't want.